# PowerShell/Batch to Remove End Text from Folder Name

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I installed the new Google Drive's software "Backup and Sync" and now all the suddenly it added the text `(1)` at the end of ALL my music folders!

It's painful going through so many artists and manually editing these... Is there any way I can use a batch file to go through each file and remove that piece string?

I've done a lot of searching and I can't seem to find any details pertaining to removing text from a **FOLDER** name. Everything I've searched is about remove text from a filename.

**Example Directory:**

```
Awesome Artist (1)
Another Cool Artist (1)
Artist Is Fun (1)
WOW COOL Artist (1)
Ok No More Artists (1)
```

**End Goal**

```
Awesome Artist
Another Cool Artist
Artist Is Fun
WOW COOL Artist
Ok No More Artists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use substring substitution (see `set /?`) to remove the unwanted string `(1)`. Put a loop around (loop over all folders (`/d`) which ends with `<space>(1)`

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM just to generate some folders to work with:
for %%a in (
  "Awesome Artist (1)"
  "Another Cool Artist (1)"
  "Artist Is Fun (1)"
  "WOW COOL Artist (1)"
  "Ok No More Artists (1)"
) do md "%%~a"
dir /ad

REM rename the folders:
for /d %%a in ("*(1)") do (
  set folder=%%a
  ren "%%a" "!folder: (1)=!"
)
dir /ad
pause
```

Note: the `ren` command will fail, when a folder with the same name already exist, preventing from overwriting.